# Can I include a button to download an attachment within an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm developing a rails application and using ActionMailer to send emails to the users. I know how to include attachments in every email. But I was wondering if I can provide a button within the mailer view to download explicitly a particular attachment as a user interface improvement.

**Update:**

I honestly forgot to mention something important about this. The eventual endpoint that I need to build in order to download the file from the email needs to be authenticated via *Authorization* header, and it's value is an  encoded token using base64. I don't know if there is a vulnerability by sending this token within the email.

Comment: I would argue sending an Authorization token in an email is almost the same than sending a password on a postcard. Why does the download URL need authorization if you send the link via email? Why is login in first (before downloading) not an option? How sensible is the token, is a one time token or could someone reuse the token for other requests?

Comment: The flow is the following: an user consumes an endpoint from an Android app to the rails server I am building. As response, a report with sensitive information (CSV file) is sent via email to the user. Because of that, the endpoint requires authentication. So, I'm thinking to create other endpoint that responds directly the CSV file, but also it has to be authenticated. The token can be reused for other requests.

Comment: Another option would be create a link to the attached CSV file, but I don't know if it's possible

Comment: IMHO the whole process would be much safer if your Android app (that is already authenticated) asked the Rails app if the report is finalized and initialized the download - instead of sending a authentication token in an email.

Comment: @spickermann thanks a lot for your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in `route.rb`

```
get "controller/action" , as: :download
```

in mailer view, add this

```
<%= link_to "DOWNLOAD", download_path %>
```

in your controller do something like

```
def download
    send_file 'path_to_your_file',:type=>"application/extension_of_your_file", :x_sendfile=>true 
end
```

**The Other way**

You can simply put your file in public folder and then just put a link to download in your mailer view like:

```
<%= link_to 'name of button', 'http:// your_website / your_file_name' %>
```

Also next time make sure to add some code to your Question about what you have tried or what you are planning to achieve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The button can link to a controller action in your rails application that sends the file down to the user just as if the user clicked to download it when browsing in your app.